# Am I a dual citizen? Can I go to Japan, where I was born?

Tags: japan, dual-nationality, filipino-citizens, japanese-citizens

I'm turning 18 in January and I was born in Japan. My mom is Filipino and my dad is Japanese. My mom brought me to the Philippines when I was 3 and I've been here for 14 years. I have a Japanese passport, but it has expired. I don't have a birth certificate here in the Philippines. My father wants to bring me back to Japan; how could the process go?

Comment: By 'go to' do you mean to visit Japan, or to move there?

Comment: oh to move there

Comment: I hope your Japanese is as good as your English!

Comment: @JamesK That's a bit harsh. Do you want OP to get deported?

Comment: I don't mean it harshly!  In some countries you can get by with English. But not in Japan. It is hard to be gaijin in Japan, and harder if you can't communicate well. But of course, as a Japanese citizen, the OP can't be deported as a non-citizen could.

Comment: Yes, i do know how to speak in japanese since that's the language i use since then when communicating with my father also i take japanese classes online 

Comment: @JamesK Are people who appear Japanese in all respects except when they open their mouth considered *gaijin* in Japan?

Comment: If you're not Japanese you're gaijin.

Comment: I think this question is better suited in Law.SE .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Citizenship of the Philippines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippine_nationality_law) is acquired by *jus sanguinis* ("by blood"), so the fact that your mother is Filipino automatically gives you citizenship of the Philippines (given your date of birth — rules have changed over time).

[Citizenship of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_nationality_law) is also acquired by *jus sanguinis*, though with a few additional conditions for people born abroad, which is not your case. Since your father is Japanese, so are you (for now, see below). The fact that you previously had a Japanese passport seems to confirm this.

So, **at this time**, you are indeed apparently a dual citizen of Japan and the Philippines.

According to the [consular affairs section of the Embassy of Japan in the Philippines](https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/00_000035.html):

- [Japan wants you to pick your nationality before you reach 22](https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000163110.pdf). [Wikipedia states that this is not enforced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_nationality_law#Dual_nationality), but of course YMMV.
- Until then, I suppose you should be able to get a passport by [applying to the Japanese embassy](https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000163107.pdf). You need:

  - to get the application form from them
  - apparently a "family register" (*koseki tohon*)
  - your expired passport
  - proof of identity
  - **consent from both parents**
  - to [pay a fee of 5200 PHP (5 year passport) or 7600 PHP (10 year passport)](https://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000455635.pdf)

You probably want to get in touch with them if you have any questions. You'll need to make an appointment anyway given the current situation with the Covid-19 pandemic.

Comment: Oh okay. But regarding the matter about going here in the Philippines when i was 3, it was supposed to be only a travel not living here so it means i am overstaying right? If yes, how much would you think the penalty would be?

Comment: @nini If you are a citizen of the Philippines, you are not overstaying.

Comment: Oh okay. Just clarifying, because it was only for a travel or vacation when i was brought here so i thought i was overstaying

Comment: @nini You can't overstay in a country you are citizen of.  You have the right to live there.

Comment: If your mother is indeed Filipino (or more accurately, if she was Filipino at the time of your birth), then you a citizen of the Philippines and you can't overstay in the Philippines. There are some instances of countries where a woman getting married automatically gets her husband's nationality and possibly loses the original one, not sure if any of that applies here.

Comment: So basically i am not overstaying here in the Philippines and i do am a dual citizen so all i need to do now is renew my passport and register my birth certificate here in the Philippines right? omg thank you very much

Comment: @nini Note that this is based on the information we have. There may be things we don't know which could change your situation.

Comment: Yes i understand, so i should might as well go to the immigration and ask about this but i do hope that i am a dual citizen and not overstaying here since by doing my research, it would cost so much and i could be blacklisted :o

Comment: Start by checking with your mother if she was indeed a Filipino citizen at the time of your birth. That's the starting point of it all.

Comment: In terms of overstay: If you are a citizen of the Philippines, it is impossible for you to be an overstayer in the Philippines. Do you have a Filipino passport? When you entered the Philippines 14 years ago, do you know if it was on your Japanese passport or a Filipino one? It's likely that you are a Filipino citizen, however, if this has never been registered anywhere, there may be headaches and paperwork caused by simply attempting to leave on a Japanese passport that was last used when you entered the Philippines 14 years ago! Make sure you have passports for both when leaving for Japan.

Comment: I just asked my mother if she was already married with my father when she gave birth to me and apparently she was already married with him at that time but my mom and dad was married in both countries, Philippines and Japan. And i have also asked her if that's the case it means she's already a Japanese citizen but she said she isn't yet since she haven't got to do the papers on registering herself as a Japanese citizen. And regarding the passport thing, i didn't had a Philippine passport by then, only a Japanese passport.

Comment: Might want to change "current situation" to "current **COVID-19 pandemic** situation".  SE is designed to encourage answers to linger on the site for years and years, good questions eventually become Google top hits or even Google on-page answers; and 9 years hence, someone will wonder "what does 'current situation' mean?

Comment: Regarding the non-enforcement of the selection policy, there is no real way for the Japanese government to enforce it. Some countries, for example, do not allow renouncing citizenship, or have strict conditions (e.g., the U.S. charges a large fee). So practically it is impossible to enforce. All that the Japanese government could do is to treat the individual as having renounced foreign citizenship.